# Derivative of $\Bbb C^{n \times n} \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

If function $f : \Bbb C^{n \times n} \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ is defined by$$ f(X) := X A X^{H} - X B - E X^{H} + F $$ find the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$. Here, $X^{H}$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose of $X$.

I want to do this as I want to find out the minimizer of  trace$(f(X))$ , so I want to differentiate and find out the optimal $X$, i.e.,

$$\underset{X}{\min} \quad\mbox{Trace} \left( f(X) \right)$$

---

How do I find the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$? I consulted the matrix cookbook but did not find the relevant results. I only found results pertaining to vectors but here the derivative is with respect to a matrix.

Comment: ① What do you mean by $X^H$ ? Isn't it $X^T$ instead ? ② A n×n matrix with real coefficients lives in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ which is a vector space : a n×n matrix *is* a vector.

Comment: Is the $F$ on the LHS of the definition differerent than the $F$ on the RHS, or do they cancel each other? The result of such a matrix-by-matrix differentiation will be a **_complex_** _fourth-order tensor_.  How do you plan to utilize such a strange object? I suspect that this is part of a larger problem, and if you describe that problem, someone here can show you how to solve it _without_ needing to calculate such an awkward tensor.

Comment: There is a subtlety here of which you may or may not be aware. Since $X$ is a complex matrix, there are holomorphic and antiholomorphic derivatives (like $\partial f/\partial z$ and $\partial f/\partial\bar z$ for a function $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$). So your notation suggests you're looking for the holomorphic "piece" of the derivative. Correct?

Comment: @TedShifrin I introduced the domain and co-domain when I saw the Hermitian transpose. The OP may disagree with it.

Comment: In which set does $X$ take values? How do you ensure the trace is not complex-valued?

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\lr{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Assume that
$A=A^H,E=B^H\;{\rm and}\;F=F^H\,$
which ensures that the trace is *real*-valued.

$\big($NB: This implies that
$\,A^*=A^T\;{\rm and}\;E^*=B^T\big)$

Let's also introduce a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
}$$
Use colon products to rewrite the objective function,
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= X:\lr{AX^H}^T - X:B^T - B^H:\lr{X^H}^T + \trace{F} \\
d\phi &= dX:\lr{X^*A^*} - dX:B^T \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= \lr{X^*A^* - B^T} \;=\; \lr{XA-E}^* \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields an optimal solution of $\;X=EA^{-1}$

Notice that during the differentiation process, $X$ and $X^H$ are treated as independent variables. This is called Wirtinger differentiation (aka the $\,\mathbb{CR}\,$- Calculus).

If you calculate the gradient wrt $X^H$ instead, you will find that
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{X^H} &= \lr{XA-E}^T \\
}$$
and the optimal solution is the same.

Comment: Is it not better to take the gradient with respect to $X^*$, i.e., complex conjugate, rather than Hermitian transpose $X^H$?

Comment: @user550103 Of course. That would yield $(XA-E)$ directly, rather than its conjugate or transpose. But all three gradients lead to the same optimal value for $X.\;$

Comment: Agreed, greg! Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's some debate about what question you intended, I'm going to address the *real* situation, as it is less complicated.

You want to compute $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial X}Y$, i.e., the directional derivative in direction $Y$ (which is another matrix). This is the best way to handle the derivative as a linear map when the inputs are matrices. I'm going to write $^\top$ for the transpose.

We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}Y &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{F(X+tY)-F(X)}t  \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac1t \big((X+tY)A(X+tY)^\top - (X+tY)B - E(X+tY)^\top+F-XAX^\top+XB +EX^\top - F\big) \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{tYAX^\top + tXAY^\top + t^2YAY^\top - tYB-tEY^\top}t \\
&= YAX^\top + XAY^\top - YB - EY^\top.
\end{align*}

Note that there is no more concise formula, as the answer involves both $Y$ and $Y^\top$.